# android.view.InflateException Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-actionbar

I am getting the following errors from logcat when I select an attempting to load an activity. Line 44 of the XML is just a scale typing. I only recieve this error on certain phones.

```
    02-14 23:50:46.555 9733-9733/com.example.jj.fragments E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jj.fragments, PID: 9733
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jj.fragments/com.example.jj.fragments.CurrentChat}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:440)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2358)
at com.example.jj.fragments.CurrentChat.onCreate(CurrentChat.java:96)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:440)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2358)
at com.example.jj.fragments.CurrentChat.onCreate(CurrentChat.java:96)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:774)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4009)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:513)
at com.android.internal.widget.AbsActionBarView.<init>(AbsActionBarView.java:74)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.<init>(ActionBarContextView.java:103)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.<init>(ActionBarContextView.java:98)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.<init>(ActionBarContextView.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:440)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2358)
at com.example.jj.fragments.CurrentChat.onCreate(CurrentChat.java:96)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

XML for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/CCLL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#303e73"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5">

    <ListView
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:background="#26315c"
        android:id="@+id/messagesLV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>

</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:background="#303e73"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/addimgbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="#303e73"
        android:src="@mipmap/whiteadd" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageET"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:lines="5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Enter your Message...">
    </EditText>


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="#303e73"
        android:src="@mipmap/whitesend" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which is line number `44 ` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not in scale typing. You are using

```
    com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
```

Make sure you are using material theme or appcompat theme for your app with the appropriate action bar.

Comment: I am using the following theme ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light

Comment: It worked on several phones and crashed on some. Which one should I use?

Comment: try using theme.appcompat.light and check

Comment: Crashed with this error "java.lang.NullPointerException" when         mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

Comment: Why not use toolbars instead of action bar

Comment: I could do that however I need the toolbar/actionbar to stay at its position when an edittext is selected. However the toolbar moves up from its view when the edittext at the bottom of the screen is clicked on.

Comment: In that case use toolbar and add the below in your manifest under activity tag      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"